# Cloudformation YAML template if else not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax, yaml, ip, aws-cloudformation

I have cloudformation file that checks if it's Apple adding IPs and else adding other IPs.

However, I want to add IPs for both Apple & not Apples without copying the IPs to both of them.

By writing it once!

When trying to do it, I get validation errors...

That's my original code -

```
SecurityGroupIngress: !If
        - IsApple
        - - Description: "Its Apple IP"
            FromPort: X
            ToPort: X
            IpProtocol: tcp
            CidrIp: X.X.X.X
        - - Description: "It's not Apple IP"
            FromPort: X
            ToPort: X
            IpProtocol: tcp
            CidrIp: X.X.X.X
```

That's the change I want -

```
SecurityGroupIngress:
         - Description: "Its *All* fruits IPs"
           FromPort: X
           ToPort: X
           IpProtocol: tcp
           CidrIp: X.X.X.X
      !If
        - IsApple
        - - Description: "Its Apple IP"
            FromPort: X
            ToPort: X
            IpProtocol: tcp
            CidrIp: X.X.X.X
        - - Description: "It's not Apple IP"
            FromPort: X
            ToPort: X
            IpProtocol: tcp
            CidrIp: X.X.X.X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move you're `!If` inside the `SecurityGroupIngress` array:

```yaml
  SecurityGroupIngress:
         - Description: "Its *All* fruits IPs"
           FromPort: X
           ToPort: X
           IpProtocol: tcp
           CidrIp: X.X.X.X
        - !If
          - IsApple
          - Description: "Its Apple IP"
            FromPort: X
            ToPort: X
            IpProtocol: tcp
            CidrIp: X.X.X.X
          - Description: "It's not Apple IP"
            FromPort: X
            ToPort: X
            IpProtocol: tcp
            CidrIp: X.X.X.X
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it the above should work.